# Что можно назвать фруктом, а что овощем?

Tags: выбор-слов, терминология

Вот, скажем, арбуз — это фрукт или овощ? Или маслины?
Что вообще принято называть фруктом, а что овощем? Интуитивно кажется, что фрукт — это нечто десертное, сладкое. Но как тогда быть с вышеупомянутым арбузом или дыней? А если считать, что фрукты — это все, что растет на деревьях и кустах, то как быть с маслинами или орехами?

Comment: Интересный вопрос. +1. Тут хотелось бы ещё и с этимологией разобраться. 

.

Я вот буквально на днях гостинцы (фрукты и овощи) от родственников с дачи рассматривал и вспомнил, что в некоторых славянских языках нет слова фрукты. Фрукты там тоже овощи (с поправкой на местное произношение).

.

Выходит что? В старину у славян не было деления овощи/фрукты? Фрукты более позднее заимствование?

Comment: А, кстати, да! А слово "плод" — славянское?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ох, замечательный вопрос. Сам недавно о том думал.

Всё дело в том, что понятия фрукта и овоща строго не формализованы даже на биологическом уровне.

А на бытовом - фрукты растут на деревьях, Овощи - на травянистых растениях, как правило - на однолетних. К сожалению, строгости тут нет, ибо есть исключения. А еще - кустарники, корнеплоды (которые, к овощам, строго говоря, не относятся), бахчевые (которые биологически - ягоды!!!), бобовые - и много еще всего, включая упомянутые маслины и орехи. Маслины, кстати, тоже ближе к ягодам, а орехи - в твердой скорлупе, поэтому выделены в отдельную категорию.

Поэтому интуитивное деление на сладкое-несладкое в общем-то вполе объяснимо. Более того есть еще ряд "небиологических" классификаторов (торговые ЕС, скажем) по которым в рязряд фруктов попадает, например, морковь. По той самой причине, что из неё варят варенье.

С кулинарной же точки зрения фрукты и ягоды - это то, чего варят компоты, кисели, варенья и проч. Овощи же и корнеплоды потребляют если не сырыми, то после варки или запекания, в качестве гарнира или ингредиентов. Но в общем-то это тоже не строгое разделение.

//-------------- 
Я знаю про костянку. Кстати, я и скразал "***скорее*** ягода".
Но по большому счёту тут разговор совсем не о биологии.

В разговоре возникла некоторое непонимание в отношении огурца и его плода, но это все-таки не про "ягоду арбуз", оставляю как есть.

Comment: С биологической точки зрения маслина - это, если мне не изменяет склероз, сочная однокостянка. Но маслины едят именно как основное блюдо, вернее, с основным блюдом, потому что они ни разу не сладкие.  
Но вообще, конечно, деление это не биологическое, а как начнешь задумываться, так мозг сломать можно)))

Comment: Арбуз на Руси раньше тоже ели исключительно вареным со смециями или сушеным. Потом додумались солить.

Answer (score 4):

Разделение на фрукты и овощи не научное, а бытовое. Поэтому определили различия Вы верно; фрукт - десерт, овощ - основное блюдо. При этом и фрукт, и овощ по размерам крупнее ягоды, которая в бытовом понимании тоже сильно разнится с биологическим определением, где помидор - ягода, а малина - нет.

Исходя из этого, дыня и арбуз - фрукты в бытовом понимании (по крайней мере не в южных регионах) и тыквины - в научном.

Comment: А чем южные регионы провинились?))) У нас это вроде как тоже десертное блюдо (хоть порой попадаются совершенно несладкие))))

Comment: Вот и не знаю десерт или нет, особенно некоторые сорта дынь.

Answer (score 3):

В белорусском языке овощи - гародніна - то, что растёт в огороде. Фрукты - садавіна - то, что растёт в саду.

Comment: Интересно. +1 от меня. 
Заходите ещё. Сравнения с белорусским языком могут быть интересны.

Answer (score 2):

Господа, всё просто: фрукт это сочный продукт, который содержит внутри семена или косточки, остальные растительные плоды - овощи. Кстати, огурец, перец и баклажан также фрукты, хотя их продают в отделах "овощи". В быту к фруктам относят сладкие сочные плоды, а несладкие - к овощам. Короче, фрукты это то, что едят на десерт. Тогда свекла должна относиться к фруктам, ведь из неё делают сахар и мармелад. Мелкие фрукты называются ягодами, хотя и здесь есть исключение - ведь арбуз тоже ягода. Так что всё достаточно условно - в древнерусском языке не было слова "фрукт", были лишь плоды и ягоды (крупные и мелкие растительные продукты). Приятного аппетита!

Answer (score 1):

В белорусском языке, который сформировался давно и сохранился идет так. Более менее соответствующие слова овощу и фрукту -это "гарОдніна", то что растет в огороде т.е. однолетние растения, и "садавІнА", то что растет в саду, т.е. плоды многолетних растений(деревья).То что в бытовом плане ягода, у нас тоже будет "ягада". Ну, а когда на стол попадает какой-нибудь нехарактерный плод, если сладкий - "фрукт", нет -"гародніна".

Comment: Это все интересно. но вопрос-то про русский язык.

Answer (score 0):

В научном смысле арбуз - это тыквина (как и огурец,дыня, тыква), а тыквины примыкают к ягодам , как и  померанцы (апельсин, лимон); иногда к ним применяют общее наименование ягоды.

Вот здесь подробно:    http://www.ug.ru/archive/37376

http://bio-faq.ru/why/why001.htm

Comment: Людмила, тыквина - это только по одной классификации, а их несколько.  
По другой - ложная ягода.
Тут только биолог может четко разобраться. 
Я, по склерозу, помню, что арбузы, дыни и тыквы - это именно ягоды (пусть и тыквины). А вот огурцы - тыквины, но ягодами не являются. Может, что-то и напутал.

Кстати, что такое "Тыквина" тоже не стоит разбираться без специцальной подготовки. "Простсой паракарпный плод", "синекарпный плод, развивающийся из нихнего глицея" и проч. Вы во всем это ориентируетесь?

Comment: Я биолог (правда, я зоолог, а по ботанике у меня в университете была тройка))). И, насколько я помню, арбуз и иже с ним — именно ягоды.

Answer (score 0):

Щи - от них и овощи. У  латышей овощи это корни ( saknes ( sak - начинать и говорить ))
ЩИ  скорее сходно с корнем  сок сочное сочиво т.е. свежие листья для супа варева. fruct - плод от корня  нести  ФР ( греч. форос ) в латыни - выношенный плод.